# Assign each value to array and access each element of the array individually

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

How would I assign `values` to a multidimensional array so that I can access each value by its index?

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
            rows = page.css('table tr td')

            times = rows.length - 16
            rows[0..times].each { |row|
                            values = row.text.gsub(/\r\n?/, "").strip
#assign to array so I could access array[0] or array[6]
            }

end
```

Also, is it possible to access the array outside of the .each block?  It seems like the only thing I'm able to do is `puts values` before the closing `}`.

I'm very new to ruby, so I'm sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
array = rows[0..times].map do |row|
  row.text.gsub(/\r\n?/, "").strip
end
```

This builds a new array out of the return value from the block which is invoked on each element of your input array.

Comment: Awesome!  that did it, thank you sir.  Can accept in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as below using [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

> Returns a new array with the results of running block once for every element in enum.

```
 array = rows[0..times].map { |row| row.text.gsub(/\r\n?/, "").strip }
```